# How to convert from a sum written out long-hand to sigma notation

Tags: summation

We have

$\color{green}{a.}$ $$\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2b}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)\left(\frac{3b}{n}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)\left(\frac{nb}{n}\right)^2 $$
$\color{green}{b.}$ $$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{b}{n}\left({\color{red}{{\frac{ib}{n}}}}\right)^2$$

So, in order to make this long and difficult sum more accessible we can put it in "summation notation", by using the sigma symbol.

As we can see in **b**, what we are trying to say is that **b** represents the sum of all the summands from the first term ($i=1$) to the n<sup>th</sup> term ($i=n$) of the common terms.  Meaning $b/n$ and something else.

Can some one explain the last part?  The origin of term in red $$\left(\frac{ib}{n}\right)^2$$ is not clear for me. How we need to operate the $i$?

Comment: if you look at the second part of each product, you can see the $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ pattern. that's how you pick up the factor of $i$

Comment: Take it backwards: If you plug in the value $1$ for $i$ in $\frac bn(\frac{ib}n)^2$ you get $\frac bn(\frac{1\cdot b}n)^2=\frac bn(\frac{b}n)^2$, which is the first summand. If you plug in $i=2$, you get the second summand, ..., if you plug in $i=n$, you get the last summand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the same path as the comments, especially that of @Hagen von Eitzen.

It's easiest to "expand out" the sum. In general you can write the sum as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$$

where $f(i)$ is a function of $i$. In your example

$$f(i) = \frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{ib}{n}  \right)^2 _.$$

You can write $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$ as $f(1)$, plus $f(2)$, plus $f(3)$, and so on upto $f(n)$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + \ldots + f(n)$$

In your example

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{ib}{n}  \right)^2 =
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{1b}{n}  \right)^2 + 
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{2b}{n}  \right)^2 + 
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{3b}{n}  \right)^2 + \ldots +
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{nb}{n}  \right)^2$$

It's worth noting that you can take out a common factor from this sum, in just the same way as you can write $ax + ay = a(x+y)$ in elementary algebra. In your case, starting off by repeating the line above, you can take out a common factor of $\frac{b}{n}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{ib}{n}  \right)^2
&=&
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{1b}{n}  \right)^2 + 
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{2b}{n}  \right)^2 + 
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{3b}{n}  \right)^2 + \ldots +
\frac{b}{n}\left(  \frac{nb}{n}  \right)^2 \\
&=&
\frac{b}{n}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2
\left[     
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \ldots + n^2 
\right] \\
&=&
\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^3
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
\end{eqnarray*}$$

and you end up with getting a much simpler sum. With experience it is possible to pull out common factors without writing out the sum long-hand.

(You can then use a [formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares) to evaluate this simpler sum.)

Answer (score 2):

You can see that in a second squared term there is another natural (in this case) term $i$, which is increasing by one with each summand. Also, what you have written can be written like this: $(\frac {b}{n})^3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$, because $ b $ and $ n $ are constant (actually, because of the distributive law of multiplication).

**EDIT:** perhaps this recursive definition for sigma notation will help:

$\sum_{i=a}^{b}f (i) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \begin{cases} &0 \text{ if } b <a \\ 
 & f (a)+\sum_{i=a+1}^{b}f (i)\text{ if } b\geq  a
\end{cases}$

Also - $ a, b\in \mathbb {Z} $.

Comment: I got $b^3/n^3$ for the common factor not $b^3/n^2$, I think there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Definitely,  my bad.